# Reduction of Heat Conduction Equation to get Diffusion Time

Tags: thermal-conductivity

There is a question that asks me to find the diffusion time assuming an initial temperature and given thermal conductivity $k$, specific heat capacity $C$ and density $\rho$. From the heat conduction equation (assuming diffusion in only one direction):

$$\frac{\rho C}{k}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2T}{\partial x^2}$$

Then there is somehow a conclusion that given the length of the diffusion wall $L$, the diffusion time is $t_D = L^2/\alpha$. How does this come about? What additional assumptions must be made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Useful scaling relations can often be obtained by replacing differentials with finite differences:

$$\frac{\rho C}{k}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2T}{\partial x^2};$$

$$\frac{\rho C}{k}\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta t}\sim\frac{\Delta T}{(\Delta x)^2}.$$

(Note that $\Delta T$ doesn't get squared on the right because the operator is $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$.)

From this we obtain $\Delta t=\frac{\rho C(\Delta x)^2}{k}=\frac{(\Delta x)^2}{\alpha}$, where $\alpha\equiv\frac{k}{\rho C}$ is the thermal diffusivity.

This relation isn't exact by any means; it just tells us that we can expect the diffusion process over distance $x$ to have progressed fairly far along by time $\frac{x^2}{\alpha}$. (For some configurations, we're at $1-e^{-1}=63\%$ of the asymptotic final solution; two time constants would give us $86\%$, and three $95\%$.) A better solution may require solution of the original differential equation.